# Fire a update trigger when particular field is updated

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

How do I fire a before update trigger only one or some particular fields are updated and not fire when other fields are updated as it causes duplicate record in other object

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Triggers aren't granular like that. In the before update trigger, use the `Trigger.New` and `Trigger.OldMap` variables to compare each new record to see if the fields you're interested in have changed.

```
for (Opportunity newOpp : Trigger.new) {
    Opportunity oldOpp = Trigger.oldMap.get(newOpp.Id);
    if (oldOpp.Name != newOpp.Name) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me a small example. I am kind of new to salesforce

Comment: `Map<ID,sObject> NewRecords = Trigger.NewMap;` http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_triggers_context_variables.htm